# How to set key value to spinner list from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I have database like this]

I have spinner and i want to add key value from firebase to set on spinner list .I use code below but not working for me.

I want to add keys value(2015-16,2016-17,2017-18) in spinner.

Here my code it's not working.

```
  DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.child("First").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final List<String> sess = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String Session = areaSnapshot.getKey();
                sess.add(Session);
            }

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AdminMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sess);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: seems like you need inner for loop , add another for loop

Comment: try  `for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          for (DataSnapshot dates: areaSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String Session = dates.getKey();
                sess.add(Session);
            }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening one level too high in your JSON tree. Your `onDataChange()` is now triggered with the `CIVIL` node, while you likely want it one level lower.

```
rootRef.child("First/CIVIL").addValueEventListener(
```

One thing to note though: this will load all data under each date, just to show that date in the spinner. If that is a significant amount of data, you're wasting your user's bandwidth.

I'd consider in that case flattening your data structure and keeping a separate node with just the dates:

```
"Dates": {
  "CIVIL": {
    "2015-16": true,
    "2016-17": true,
    "2017-18": true
  }
}
```

The `true` values are just needed to make sure Firebase doesn't delete the keys. Downloading this branch of the JSON ensures you only download the minimum data that is needed to populate the spinner.